# Can I use DataAnnotations with Viewmodel classes?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, automapper

In my solution I have an ASP.NET MVC3 project, and a WCF project that works with a database. I will use `AutoMapper` to map objects.

My question is: can I use DataAnnotations with my viewmodel classes, and map them to objects received from the WCF service project?

Like

```
public class User
{
    [Required,MaxLength(30)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can use DataAnnotations with your View Model classes, and i didn't quiet understand what the second part means, probably yes

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use them for two things:

- Entity Framework mappings to tell Entity Framework how to generate a column (although I usually use the fluent API for this)
- Input validation, so this is where your ViewModel comes in. You can annotate it with the dataannotations,  and use jquery.validate and MVC's ModelState.IsValid to verify that all requirements were met.

When everything is alright you can map the ViewModel to a POCO/entity without annotations.